# Select variable dynamic value

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

(I already declared the variables)

I have the below query

```
select @VCOUNT = count(1) from @TMP_NAME||'TAB1'||@TIME
```

giving the below error

> Incorrect syntax near '@TMP_NAME'

The tmp_name and time are dynamic.

The query was like this and it worked:

```
select @VCOUNT = count(1) from tab1
```

How to add dynamic to select variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the entire select statement into a string containing Sql e.g. @Sql

```
select @Sql = 'select @VCOUNT = count(1) from ' + @TMP_NAME + 'TAB1' + @TIME
```

then use EXEC for dynamic sql:

```
EXEC(@Sql)
```

@VCOUNT will be set inside the dynamic sql and will be available outside the dynamic statement.

As it's dynamic you'll not have the benefit of stored query plans for this statement if this is inside an SP, but that might not be significant, it depends.

Comment: Abe is right, you need to put it into a string. This is the answer to your problem.

Comment: thanks for your asnwer , Ill already did that yesterday and it worked fine, hope this question will help people in the future